# Bootstrap will not put my two tables in two columns next to one another

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Trying to put two tables next to one another. One `col-md-4` and the other `col-md-8` I want the 4 to be on the left and the 8 to be on the right. Left table being game messages and buttons while the right table is the tic tac toe board. My understanding is when using bootstrap I just need columns to add up to a total of 12.

```
 </head>
  <body class="bodyNormal">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
          <h3 class="mainimg">Tic Tac Toe Game</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row bg-white">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <button class="btn" id="newGame"> New game</button>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <h2 class="player1Turn hidden">Player 1 Turn</h2>
                <h2 class="player2Turn hidden">Player 2 Turn</h2>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td class="grid">7<img src="X.jpg"</td>
              <td class="vert grid">8<img src="O.jpg"</td>
              <td class="grid">9<img src="X.jpg"</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="hori grid">4<img src="O.jpg"</td>
              <td class="vert hori grid">5<img src="X.jpg"</td>
              <td class="hori grid">6<img src="O.jpg"</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="grid">1<img src="X.jpg"</td>
              <td class="vert grid">2<img src="O.jpg"</td>
              <td class="grid">3<img src="X.jpg"</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot one `div` close for `col-md-4`

```
</table></div> /*Close Here One div*/
        <div class="col-md-8">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/y0k4bs6p/3/

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you forgot to close div for col-md-4.

Updated code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
      <h3 class="mainimg">Tic Tac Toe Game</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row bg-white">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <button class="btn" id="newGame"> New game</button>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>2</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <h2 class="player1Turn hidden">Player 1 Turn</h2>
              <h2 class="player2Turn hidden">Player 2 Turn</h2>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="grid">7<img src="X.jpg" </td>
          <td class="vert grid">8<img src="O.jpg" </td>
          <td class="grid">9<img src="X.jpg" </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="hori grid">4<img src="O.jpg" </td>
          <td class="vert hori grid">5<img src="X.jpg" </td>
          <td class="hori grid">6<img src="O.jpg" </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="grid">1<img src="X.jpg" </td>
          <td class="vert grid">2<img src="O.jpg" </td>
          <td class="grid">3<img src="X.jpg" </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're right! Thank you so much for taking a glance at it!